# Python 3: Managing keyword arguments hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, keyword-argument, code-documentation

I am working on python 3, with some methods that are nested.
These shares keyword arguments something like below.

```py
def fun_A(a, **kwargs):
    ...
    fun_B(**kwargs)
    ...

def fun_B(b, **kwargs):
    ...
    fun_C(c)
    ...

def fun_C(c=some_default_value):
    ...
```

With this code, when someone calls `fun_A`, `'b'` and optionally, `'c'` should be in `kwargs`. Also, calling `fun_B` requires optionally `'c'` in `kwargs`.

The nested structure of sharing `kwargs` could be more complicated. I wonder if there are any automatic tools to give hints for `kwargs`, describing the arguments required and their default values in sub-methods.

eg.) When you see the [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) of `fun_A`, the tool may attach some information about `kwargs`, saying you need to specify `b` and optionally `c` and its default value is `some_default_value`.

Thank you.